# Error in R term frequency analysis (TF-IDF)

Tags: r, text, tf-idf, tidytext

I tried to run the following code with the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidytext)

book_words <- austen_books() %>%
 unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
 count(book, word, sort = TRUE)
```

For this, I get this error message:

```
Error in count(., book, word, sort = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (sort = TRUE)
```

What do I have to change for the code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that `count` from `dplyr` got masked from any other package loaded with having the same function `count`.  So, use `dplyr::count`

```
austen_books() %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
  dplyr::count(book, word, sort = TRUE)
# A tibble: 40,379 × 3
   book              word      n
   <fct>             <chr> <int>
 1 Mansfield Park    the    6206
 2 Mansfield Park    to     5475
 3 Mansfield Park    and    5438
 4 Emma              to     5239
 5 Emma              the    5201
 6 Emma              and    4896
 7 Mansfield Park    of     4778
 8 Pride & Prejudice the    4331
 9 Emma              of     4291
10 Pride & Prejudice to     4162
# … with 40,369 more rows
```

i.e. if we have loaded `plyr` after `dplyr`, it may mask some of the common functions available in `dplyr`

```
> austen_books() %>%
+   unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
+   plyr::count(book, word, sort = TRUE)
Error in plyr::count(., book, word, sort = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (sort = TRUE)
```